# jQuery: number of siblings of same tag name

Tags: jquery

Here I come with a jQuery problem. Consider this random element:

```
<div id="some_random_id">
  <b></b>
  <div></div>
  <b></b>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**All we have is a pointer to a child element**. We know nothing about the parent element. We need to write a function, that outputs the NUMBER of siblings of the same tag name.

```
function n_siblings_same_tagname(this){};
```

Function has to return 2 when our object is of DIV tag name and 1 when the tag name is B. How do we do that? Thanks

Comment: The other divs inside the div with id = 'some_random_id' are children, not siblings. Could you please change the title to reflect that ?

Comment: Yeah, true. And we know nothing about the parent element. All we know is a pointer to a child element and other child elements are siblings to the element, that we know

Comment: If we return those numbers then you're not retrieving the number of siblings with the given tag-name, you're finding all children with that tag-name, siblings plus original. Please could you [edit] your question to specify exactly what you want?

Comment: Just edited. What I wanted is the number of all the elements of the same tag as the element given. Just edited to siblings only as it's easier to understand and the way of getting the answer does not change much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function n_siblings_same_tagname(node){

  // Retrieve the tagName of the passed-in
  // DOM node:
  var elType = node.tagName;

  // Converting the children the passed-node's
  // parent's element children into an Array, 
  // using Array.from():
  return Array.from( node.parentNode.children )

    // filtering that array, using an Arrow
    // which retains only those elements
    // whose tagName is equal to the
    // tagName of the passed-in elementary:
      .filter( elem => elem.tagName == elType )
    // finding the length of the filtered Array, and
    // subtracting 1, as we want siblings not all
    // elements of that type:
      .length - 1;
}
```

Or, if jQuery is preferred:

```
function n_siblings_same_tagname(element){

  // we may receive a jQuery object, or a DOM
  // node; here we wrap the received element
  // with jQuery:
  var el = $(element);

  // returning the length of the number of 
  // sibling elements matching the
 //  supplied selector, here the tagName
 // of the passed in element, and
  return el.siblings(el.prop('tagName')).length
}
```

Given the response from the OP, in comments below, I'd offer the alternative of:

```
function n_siblings_same_tagname(element){

  // we may receive a jQuery object, or a DOM
  // node; here we wrap the received element
  // with jQuery:
  var el = $(element);

  // returning the length of the number of 
  // child elements matching the selector
  // provided by the tagName property
   // of the passed-in element:
  return el.parent().children(el.prop('tagName')).length
}
```

Or, the amended JavaScript:

```
function n_siblings_same_tagname(node){

  // Retrieve the tagName of the passed-in
  // DOM node:
  var elType = node.tagName;

  // Converting the children the passed-node's
  // parent's element children into an Array, 
  // using Array.from():
  return Array.from( node.parentNode.children )

    // filtering that array, using an Arrow
    // which retains only those elements
    // whose tagName is equal to the
    // tagName of the passed-in elementary:
      .filter( elem => elem.tagName == elType )
    // finding the length of the filtered Array:
      .length;
}
```

Comment: My mistake, what I meant is the element itself and all its siblings. In any case the logic of the answer does not change much. Thank you for this answer

Answer (score 3):

This should select all children of your parent with the same tag:

```
function n_siblings_same_tagname(element){
    element = $(element);
    return element.parent().children(element.prop("tagName")).length;
};
```

Comment: This assumes that `this` is a jQuery object not a DOMElement, but would work in that case. You just need to return the `length` property.

Comment: What's the first line for?

Comment: as rory stated it could be, that element is not a jquery object. If you are sure to only call it with jQuery Objects you can remove the line